# MYSQL Index strategy when no WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE gotrax1.wifi_log (
    WifiID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UnitID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ServerTime timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (),
    FileTime bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    WLANTYPE text DEFAULT NULL,
    MACSRC varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    MACDST varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    BSSID varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    SIG int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ESSID text DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (WifiID)
)
```

I need to run this query on it

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACDST)) AS MACDST,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACSRC)) AS MACSRC,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(BSSID)) AS BSSID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACDST))-COUNT(DISTINCT(MACSRC)) AS UnitDIFF,
    UnitID, FileTime, WLANTYPE
FROM wifi_log 
GROUP BY FileTime,UnitID,WLANTYPE
ORDER BY FileTime DESC;
```

It is dog slow and does a full file sort. Normally I know to add an index following the order of a where clause. I have no idea how to do it with this query and this table to avoid the filesort. Any suggestions would be terrific thankyou.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT)` will also slow things down.

Comment: run `explain select ...` to see the execution plan.

Comment: You can have 2 indexes 1. complex index [FileTime,UnitID,WLANTYPE] and 1. for fileTime in  a desc order. check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/order-by-column-should-have-index-or-not)

Comment: Thanks I had run explain prior to posting and all is says is using filesort (which I included above)

Comment: thanks I added these two indexes (I had put DESC on the filetime but it didnt seem to stick. no difference still using filesort ALTER TABLE gotrax1.wifi_log
ADD INDEX IDX_wifi_log_FileTime (FileTime);

ALTER TABLE gotrax1.wifi_log
ADD INDEX IDX_wifi_log2 (FileTime, UnitID, WLANTYPE (1));

Comment: for COUNT(DISTINCT) sure I dont know any other way to get the result I need though

Comment: Ever think to break the table apart?  Example:  Pulling all of your varchar out to a table and using an Int indexer, as int compare is faster than string compare.  Generally, if a lot of things can be referenced from within a row, i create a new table as N* vachar(25) is more costly in size as opposed to int.  If its always unique, you gain nothing, but if there can be duplicates, it pays dividends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an index on `WLANTYPE` as it is, because if you try to index a TEXT or BLOB, you get this error:

> ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'wlantype' used in key specification without a key length

I would question whether you need WLANTYPE to be TEXT. Perhaps a shorter VARCHAR would be just as good.

```
alter table wifi_log modify wlantype varchar(10);
```

Then you can add a covering index:

```
alter table wifi_log add key (filetime,unitid,wlantype,macdst,macsrc,bssid);
```

Also get rid of the `ORDER BY FileTime` so you don't have to sort the result. Sort the result after fetching the result in your application, if it isn't already in the order you want.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACDST)) AS MACDST,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACSRC)) AS MACSRC,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(BSSID)) AS BSSID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACDST))-COUNT(DISTINCT(MACSRC)) AS UnitDIFF,
    UnitID, FileTime, WLANTYPE
FROM wifi_log 
GROUP BY FileTime,UnitID,WLANTYPE
ORDER BY NULL\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: wifi_log
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: FileTime
          key: FileTime
      key_len: 366
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
```

The **type: index** in this explain report shows that it still has to scan the whole index, which is nearly as expensive as a table-scan. But that's natural for your query, which needs to get counts from every row.

The advantage of making this an index scan may be that it has to examine fewer pages. One index, even on 6 columns, is smaller than the whole table.

Also getting rid of the filesort will help.

Comment: I doubt if there is an extra sort for the `ORDER BY` since it adequately matches the `GROUP BY`.  This would indicate whether there is an extra sort:  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...`

Comment: I see you're right! I get _"using_filesort": false,_ in the JSON EXPLAIN report.

Comment: So the best optimization is to use the index-scan instead of a table-scan. I doubt that will make much difference at the end of the day.

Comment: First, "covering" gives a speedup.  Then there are two _potential_ sorts to try to avoid.  I would expect the first 3 columns of your index to avoid the 'filesort' for `GROUP BY`; does it?  Then, the similarity between `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` should obviate the filesort for `ORDER BY`.  And, in getting rid of the first filesort, the "temp table" may go away.  I see that a 4 possible speedups.  (Need to see the schema and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` to know for sure.)  Also, is it InnoDB??

Comment: It's always InnoDB. What else? :-)  I didn't populate the table with any data, which could also make a difference. If you want to do all that work and post your own answer, be my guest. :)

Comment: There are a few MyISAM stragglers out there!  (So I have to ask.)

Comment: I don't think it's worth spending time on optimizing cases of MyISAM stragglers.

Comment: If the OP were using MyISAM, some of your advice might not work.  And some people still recommend MyISAM for "logs".

Answer (score 0):

I have a technique for approximating `COUNT(DISTINCT..)` from summarized data.  Could you build daily summaries of the data?  Then roll up the data for the totals?  Such is easy for `COUNT` (sum of counts) and `SUM` (sum of sums), but rather tricky for 'uniques'.  It gives only approximations, usually within 1% of the exact result.  Here is an overview of the technique:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uniques

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a column to hold the hash of your WLANTYPE.

add index to the hash's column and a trigger to set it in insert / update..

and change your query a bit for:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACDST)) AS MACDST,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACSRC)) AS MACSRC,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(BSSID)) AS BSSID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(MACDST))-COUNT(DISTINCT(MACSRC)) AS UnitDIFF,
    UnitID, FileTime, max(WLANTYPE) as WLANTYPE
FROM wifi_log 
GROUP BY FileTime,UnitID,WLANTYPEHash
ORDER BY FileTime DESC;
```

see fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16e86ea77eb242d2339d6050a1772b60